# Adding attachments to PDF

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I m using the following code to add attachments to an exiting pdf file.

```
PdfFileSpecification fs = PdfFileSpecification.fileEmbedded(stamper.getWriter(), attachTempFile.getAbsolutePath(), new String(attachment.getName().getBytes(), "UTF-8"), null);
                        stamper.addFileAttachment(new String(attachment.getName().getBytes(), "UTF-8"), fs);
```

The PDF getting created with the right attachments but the attachment names which suppose to be in hebrew are missing. Thought I m passing the attachment name in a utf-8 string it not working. if the attachments names are in EN it works fine.

How do I set encoding to the stamper object to save everything in utf-8?

Comment: What do you think that `new String(attachment.getName().getBytes(), "UTF-8")` does, and why do you do that? Assuming `attachment.getName()` returns a string, using `getBytes()` and `new String` this way is (very) wrong, especially if you are running on Windows, in which case `getBytes()` could return for example windows-1255 bytes, then your conversion using `new String(bytes, "UTF-8")` will then result in a lot of unicode replacement characters for hebrew, and `?` for characters that weren't in windows-1255.

Comment: To be clear, strings in Java themselves have no character set (though the implementation either uses iso-8859-1 or UTF-16). Character set is only relevant when converting to and from bytes, and when you use the wrong character sets when converting, you get garbage or mojibake.